# modprobe: Key was rejected by service (Ubuntu 22.04.1 Desktop ISO)

Tags: 20.04, kernel, iso, zfs

The installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 works fine, but when running the live system (ISO/USB, "Try Ubuntu") there seems to be a problem with unsigned or wrongly signed kernel modules:

```
modprobe zfs
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'zfs': Key was rejected by service
```

To reproduce:

- Download `ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso` from [here](https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04/ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso)
- Write the ISO file to a USB stick (I've used Fedora Media Writer)
- Boot from the stick, select USB entry in the grub menu
- Click the "Try Ubuntu" button
- Open a terminal
- Run `modprobe zfs`

Comment: Disable Secure Boot.

Comment: Secure Boot was never enabled on my machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error is related to secure boot. While you have mentioned in the comments that it was never enabled, it seems likely that it was already turned on in the BIOS. You can check with `mokutil --sb-state`

More info about signing modules can be found in this thread: https://superuser.com/q/1438279

Comment: You're right (and Pilot6 was also right). Seems like a bug in my BIOS, because after I enabled Secure Boot and then disabled it again, the problem was gone.