# Unbuntu 22.04 cannot find wifi realtec 10ec:b852

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek-wireless

I'm new to Ubuntu and installed 22.04 last week on my HP 27 inch all in one, model All-in-One cb1xxx. I've read and tried several solutions that have solved this problem for others, but my wifi is still not found. I'm using a wifi extender wired to my pc for now. I don't know how to paste nice boxes, please forgive the pastes...
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3 shows:

```
000:02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852]    
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:88e3]    
    Kernel modules: rtw_8852be
```

From what I've read rtw89pci is the latest driver for this device and modinfo rtw89pci shows:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.19.0-40-kreneric/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw89/rtw89pci.ko    
license:        Dual BSD/GPL    
description:    Realtek 802.11ax wireless PCI driver    
author:         Realtek Corporation    
srcversion:     C7898C387521DB0BA6F2D9E    
depends:        rtw89core,mac80211    
retpoline:      Y    
name:           rtw89pci    
vermagic:       5.19.0-40-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions    
parm:           disable_clkreq:Set Y to disable PCI clkreq support (bool)    
parm:           disable_aspm_l1:Set Y to disable PCI ASPM L1 support (bool)    
parm:           disable_aspm_l1ss:Set Y to disable PCI L1SS support (bool)
```

Comment: The correct driver is shown here: `Kernel modules: rtw_8852be` However, it appears to not be in use. Let's check the log to see why. Please edit your question to show the result of: `sudo dmesg | grep rtw` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I entered the command  sudo dmesg | grep rtw    and no information, just another prompt (after entering my password).   Thank you for getting back so soon!

Comment: Please try: `sudo modprobe -r rtw_8852be` and then: `sudo modprobe rtw_8852be` and finally: `sudo dmesg | grep rtw` I suspect you need firmware.

Comment: My apologies, I cannot figure out how to highlight text.    The first command  seems to have worked with no problem, but no output. The second one    resulted in :   modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtw_8852be': Key was rejected by service

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1455528/modprobe-key-was-rejected-by-service-ubuntu-22-04-1-desktop-iso Please turn off Secure Boot and see if the wireless springs to life.

Comment: Yes, SecureBoot was enabled. After turning off SecureBoot, wifi is found and working. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!!  Peter Dobroff.

Comment: Yes, turning off SecureBoot worked, wifi is now working.  THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!