# Wifi is not showing up

Tags: wireless, 22.04

I am using using `Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS`. It was showing wifi but after upgrading, wifi is not showing up. I have tried to run this command:

```
sudo modprobe 8821ce
```

But it is giving me error like this:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8821ce': Key was rejected by service
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [modprobe: Key was rejected by service (Ubuntu 22.04.1 Desktop ISO)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1455528/modprobe-key-was-rejected-by-service-ubuntu-22-04-1-desktop-iso)

Answer (score 0):

This has solved the issue.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-oem-20.04
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-oem-20.04
```

This has solved the issue.