# Attempting to install realtek-r8152, getting Key was rejected by service error

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek

I'm moving back to Ubuntu today and amongst some other things i wanted to get my Ethernet adapter working so i can install things faster, problem is that after looking at the guides

(example:
https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxhardware/comments/15p7lhe/realtek_25gbs_support_for_linux/?rdt=46805, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJ0gcA778Ms)

Everything seems more or less on track until i attempt to activate the driver which gives me this

```
# modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'r8152': Key was rejected by service
```

Here is the list of things I did on this attempt:

[image]

Is there something I might have missed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [modprobe: Key was rejected by service (Ubuntu 22.04.1 Desktop ISO)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1455528/modprobe-key-was-rejected-by-service-ubuntu-22-04-1-desktop-iso)